# how to arrange multiple api response in single array with in fixed format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we need to arrange item in fixed format (by category) that are comming from multiple API's response ex: 
first to need to display all laptops, second display all PC's and so on..

```
    //fixed order
    this.itemList = [{
        id: '1', 
        name: 'Apple', 
        category: 'LAPTOP'
      }, {
        id: '2', 
        name: 'HP', 
        category: 'LAPTOP'
      }, {
        id: '3', 
        name: 'DELL', 
        category: 'PC'
      }, {
        id: '4', 
        name: 'SAMSUNG', 
        category: 'MOBILE'
      }, {
        id: '5', 
        name: 'LENOVO', 
        category: 'MOBILE'
      }];
```

here we don't want to call parallel api because of response delay, we need to show items according to api response but on ui the format fixed once all api response completed. Here is method for calling api:

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemList = [];
    this.itemService.getItems('LAPTOP').then((items) => {
      this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(items);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('PC').then((items) => {
      this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(items);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('TABLET').then((items) => {
      this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(items);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('MOBILE').then((items) => {
      this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(items);
    });
}
```

So, if mobile api's response comes first, ui will display mobile items, after  that if laptop api's response comes, it will show laptop first with maintain above format. thanks

Comment: can you explain what do you want exactly i can't understand

Comment: you can use `orderBy` in your repeat but that will have a particular order and not like whichever comes first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in this case, you could do something like this:

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemList = [ [], [], [], [] ];
    this.itemService.getItems('LAPTOP').then((items) => {
      this.itemList[0] = items;
      render(this.itemList);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('PC').then((items) => {
      this.itemList[1] = items;
      render(this.itemList);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('TABLET').then((items) => {
      this.itemList[2] = items;
      render(this.itemList);
    });
    this.itemService.getItems('MOBILE').then((items) => {
      this.itemList[3] = items;
      render(this.itemList);
    });
}
```

Where render is the function that will going to update your page with your new data :

```
function render(items) {
    var flatItems = [].concat.apply([], items);
    // do page update...
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Fexfux this is good option too but we implemented throgh angular filter, thanks for your effort, this is result actually want.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Promise, Promise.all return responses in order:

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemList = [];
    Promise.all([
         this.itemService.getItems('LAPTOP'),
         this.itemService.getItems('PC'),
         this.itemService.getItems('TABLET'),
         this.itemService.getItems('MOBILE')
    ]).then((values) => {
         this.itemList = [].concat(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
    }).catch((err) => console.log('don\'t forget to handle error'));
}
```

Comment: or, using `$q` of Angular, `$q.all` gets the same result

Comment: actully i don't want to call api in such a way(parallel) as i wrote above, because i need to display lazy load.

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise .

suppose you have 4 methods

> getLaptop();
>   getPc() ;
>   getTablet();
>   getMobile();

and use in chained methods like

```
 var dataList = [];
 $q.all({'laptop': getLaptop,'pc': getPc, 'tablet':getTablet, 'mobile':getMobile}).then(function(data) {
  angular.extend(dataList, data.laptop, data.pc, data.tablet, data.mobile);
}).catch(function(err) {
console.error('Error:', err);
});
```